# Get Second Occuring date for same Id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables

Table 1

```
Employee ID     HireDate 
1               2009-09-01
2               2009-09-04
1               2009-08-04
```

Table 2:

```
Employee ID     EndDate
1               2009-09-01
1               2009-08-04
```

Table 3: ( What I am getting from my query)

```
Employee ID     EndDate
1               2009-09-01
1               2009-09-01
```

I want the Indate column in Table 2 to be updated from the value in HireDate value in Table 1 for each employee. The condition is

1. When the Employee ID occurs the first time in table 2, I should get the earliest Indate corresponding to that employee ID .
2. If the same employee Id occurs again the I should get the Second earliest date.

The query I am using..

```
UPDATE Test.dbo.Table1
    SET EndDate  = b.MinBDate
FROM Test.dbo.Table1  a
OUTER APPLY
(    
    SELECT MIN(b.HireDate) MinBDate
    FROM Test.dbo.Table2 b
    WHERE a.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID
) b
```

Answer (score 1):

You query is getting the earliest date, not the second earliest one.  Also, the update statement is referring to the wrong table.  It needs to use the alias defined in the `from` clause.  So you query should be more like:

```
UPDATE a
    SET EndDate  = b.MinBDate
FROM Test.dbo.Table1 a OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 b.HireDate as MinBDate
      FROM Test.dbo.Table2 b
      WHERE a.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID
      ORDER BY b.HireDate
     ) b;
```

For the second earliest date:

```
UPDATE a
    SET EndDate = b.HireDate
FROM Test.dbo.Table1 a OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 HireDate
      FROM (SELECT TOP 2 b.HireDate as HireDate
            FROM Test.dbo.Table2 b
            WHERE a.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID
            ORDER BY b.HireDate ASC
           ) b
      ORDER BY HireDate DESC
     ) b
```

You can also write the logic using `row_number()`, which is more likely how I would do it.  However, you started with `outer apply`, so I've kept that structure.

EDIT:

I would write this as:

```
UPDATE a
    SET EndDate = b.HireDate
FROM Test.dbo.Table1 a join
     (SELECT b.HireDate as HireDate,
             row_number() over (partition by b.EmployeeId order by HireDate) as seqnum
      FROM Test.dbo.Table2 b
     ) b
     ON a.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID and seqnum = 2;
```

The `outer apply` probably has better performance.  I just prefer this method because it works across more databases.

Comment: how would you do the same using row_number()?

Comment: The first one does not work.. I am still getting the same Date for all the occurences.

Comment: The first query is just intended to fix your code.  The second and third queries get the second date.

Comment: Yes, I tried the second and third and still the same.. No changes